# Generic View SwiftUI with ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm looking for a solution with View and polymorphism. I'v a a protocol with a special ViewModel
like that:

```
protocol PQuestionView: View {
    associatedtype VM where VM : BaseQuestionViewModel
    var vm: Self.VM { get }
}
```

so I can use it in a struct like that:

```
struct test: PQuestionView {
    var vm:YesNoQuestionViewModel = YesNoQuestionViewModel(question: Question(), temporaryId: 3)
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Yes")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have an array of PQuestionView:

```
var questionViews: [PQuestionView]
```

But I have two associated types, it seems that way of implementing view doesn't work as polymorphism. So I tried something like that:

```
struct StrongView<MyView: View,VM: BaseQuestionViewModel> : PQuestionView{
    var vm: VM
    var body: MyView
}
```

But it's have a strongly typed struct and it doesn't answer to my genericity problem... Does a good solution exists to that job?

Comment: I assume that `var questionViews: [PQuestionView]` gives the error of `Protocol 'PQuestionView' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`... You cannot do that. Can't you declare `PQuestionView` as: `protocol PQuestionView: View {
    var vm: BaseQuestionViewModel { get }
}`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how it could be used (due to absent all types I replicate those with simple stub).

Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Please note, it is not allowed to place different types in one container, so if you intended to do this you'll need type erasure, like SwiftUI `AnyView` do for `View`.

```
protocol BaseQuestionViewModel {
}

struct YesNoQuestionViewModel: BaseQuestionViewModel {
}

protocol PQuestionView: View {
    associatedtype VM where VM : BaseQuestionViewModel
    var vm: Self.VM { get }
}

struct test: PQuestionView {
    var vm = YesNoQuestionViewModel()
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Yes")
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionsHolder<T: PQuestionView>: View {
    var questionViews: [T]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<questionViews.count) { i in
            self.questionViews[i]
        }
    }
}

struct TestViewGenerics_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        List {
            QuestionsHolder(questionViews: [test(), test(), test()])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but if I add struct test2: PQuestionView {
    var vm = AnotherVmFromBase()
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("test2")
        }
    }
} and I tried QuestionsHolder(questionViews: [test(), test2(), test()]) but I cannot have several types in my array, i think this is here where I need type erasure ...

Comment: do you have an idea ?